# Logging user interactions with a program

Tags: user-interface, log4j, user-input

We have an app and we want to log how the user is interacting with it. For example are they using the pages we expect them to. I dont want to log this via the app as it will be very hard for me to then get this information from the device. Each page interacts with webservices so I was planning to log that interaction.

I have had some thoughts on this
* as the webservice is being called add a logging table to the database - problem here could be performance impact
* use log4j async mode to log these details.

Does anyone have any other suggestion on how to do this? Im reading the Lean Startup at the moment (very good so far) and this sort of thing seems fundamental to it so Im wondering if there are any other tips to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered this for a couple months, I thought a couple pointers might help you...

1. Use mobile analytics tools

   - [Fabric.io](http://Fabric.io)
   - [Google Analytics for Mobile Apps](https://www.google.com/analytics/mobile/)
   - [Flurry](https://developer.yahoo.com)
   - [Amazon Mobile Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/)
   - [appsee](https://www.appsee.com)
2. Have the server record what users access (that's the approach you're considering). To offload the overhead, there are a couple tactics you could employ (mix 'n match as you will):

   - Use async mechanisms (async operations in the server, such as Futures; log4j async mode; async databases; etc).
   - Use a separate database.
   - Use a NoSQL database only to write accesses. Later on you process that information in a separate analytics application.
3. Have the client (mobile app) record the actions and send them in bulk to the server once in a while (as frequently as you need / want / can afford).

Cheers